# Select an option from the first of two drop-downs with same class name

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu

I have selected the lowest fare and clicked on view seats and am trying to select an option from the first drop-down(boarding point), but am not able to do it as both of them have the same class name. Help is appreciated.

The code which I have used is:

```
package week3.redbus;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class BookATicket {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //page1
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtSource")).sendKeys("Hyderabad");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtDestination")).sendKeys("Chennai");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtOnwardCalendar")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'rbcal_txtOnwardCalendar']/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[@id = 'searchBtn']")).click();


        List <WebElement> fares = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/span[@class = 'fareSpan']//span"));
        int fareNum = fares.size();     
        int[] fareInt = new int [fareNum];
        int index =0;
        System.out.println( "Num of fares is "+fareNum );
        for (WebElement e : fares) {
            String fareN = e.getText();
            fareInt[index] = Integer.parseInt(fareN);//convert string to integer array
            index++;

        }
        for (int i : fareInt) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
        Arrays.sort(fareInt);//sort to ascending order
        System.out.println("Sorted fare list");

        for (int i : fareInt) {
            System.out.println(i);          
        }

        //the least price
        System.out.println("Lowest price is "+fareInt[0]);
        String x = Integer.toString(fareInt[0]);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text() = '"+ x +"']/../../../button[@class = 'viewSeatsBtn']")).click();


        //if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class ='select-apsrtc']/option[text() = '-- Boarding points --']")).isDisplayed()) {
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer BPContainer']/select")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
            Select bp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer BPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']")));
            bp.selectByIndex(6);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'continueBtn']")).click();

        //} 


    }           
}
```

@AGill By doing the above code, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (471.5, 105.80000305175781). Other element would receive the click: <div class="SortBar clearfix MB"></div>
```

@ dcsohl I have modified the last part of the code as you mentioned, but I am getting the same exception as above.

```
List<WebElement> dd = driver.findElements(By.className("select-apsrtc"));
        int ddN = dd.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < ddN; i++) {
            WebElement dd1 = dd.get(0);
            Select bp = new Select(dd1);

            //Select bp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer BPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']")));
            bp.selectByIndex(6);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'continueBtn']")).click();
        }
```

@AGill, I modified the code as you suggested as follows:

```
Select bp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer BPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']")));
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            bp.selectByVisibleText("Ameerpet - 05:25 PM");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'show-seatLayout']")).click();
```

But, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate element with text: Ameerpet - 05:25 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following locators (css selector) to uniquely identify the two drop downs. 
Locator for the Boarding point drop down will be:

```
[class='selectContainer BPContainer'] [class='select-apsrtc']
```

And locator for Dropping point drop down will be:

```
 [class='selectContainer DPContainer'] [class='select-apsrtc']
```

You can use xPath too if you want. You already have a correct xPath for boarding ponit.
For dropping point use:

```
//div[@class = 'selectContainer DPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Select bp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer BPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']")));
        bp.selectByIndex(6);

Select droppingPoint = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'selectContainer DPContainer']/select[@class = 'select-apsrtc']")));
        droppingPoint.selectByIndex(1);
```

Let me know if you have any question about this.

Comment: Thank your, for your response. I know how to select both of them by xpath as you said above.But, I need to select only the first dropbox option as the second one was already selected. I am getting an exception, when I used it, which I posted in my question. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yeah sure, can you try replacing the code line `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'continueBtn']")).click();` with `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'show-seatLayout']")).click();`.
I copied and ran your code and got error at last line.

Comment: Also add some wait for trial purposes before clicking on the button in last step.

Comment: The error you posted in question says "element is not clickable". means you are getting error while clicking on the element not while selecting drop down option.

Comment: I was editing while you were reading. Sorry :) I posted it now.

Comment: I even changed it to select by value and gave the value, It was giving not clickable error. Whatever I do, I am getting either of the two above mentioned exceptions.

Comment: It does not work because the text doesn't match. There are TWO SPACE characters after the "Ameerpet - 05:25 PM". So it's "Ameerpet - 05:25 PM  " actually.

Comment: I tried that also. Not working. Is it working for you? Sorry for all this trouble.

Comment: Yes it worked for me. `bp.selectByVisibleText("Ameerpet - 05:25 PM  ");`

Comment: I am using the same code which you gave, but whatever I do, it is giving the exception as not clickable or cant locate. I am not able to understand what the problem is. Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: I got it. The problem seems to be with my browser. The same code worked when I tried later. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`findElements()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) instead of `findElement()`. This will return you a `List<WebElement>` instead of a single `WebElement`, and you can choose the first or second item in the list.

Comment: I am getting the following exception if I use findElements() : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Comment: Please don't try to put stack traces in a comment. Edit the original question with additional information so other possible answerers will see it more easily.

Comment: Yes, `findElements()` returns a `List<WebElement>`, exactly as I said it does. You already have one place you are using `findElements()` (look at `fares`), so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I can't or not able to use findElements() with Select.There I am able to give only findElement().

Comment: I really can't help you if you can't be more specific. *What sort of problems are you having?* You haven't indicated why you can't use `findElement()`.

Comment: I am trying to select a drop-down (Boarding point) menu using the Select class. You can see it in the last part of my code. But am not able to do it. It might be because there is one more dropdown menu (dropping point) beside it.

Comment: Ok, let's back up. My suggestion was to us `findElements()` instead of `findElement()`. This will give you a list of WebElements instead of a single WebElement, and you can choose the first or the second one. Your response is, "I can't." Why can't you?

Comment: Because for dropdown menu, I have to create an instance of Select class and use it to select the options. In select class, I can give only findelement() to select. If I give findElement(), It gives the above stated exception.

Comment: Because the constructor to [`Select()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#Select-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) takes one `WebElement` and will not accept a `List<WebElement>`. You have to call `findElements()`, take the first (or second) `WebElement` out of the `List` and **then** pass it into `Select()`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have done as you said. I posted it in my question on how I modified it. But I was getting an exception as mentioned above. Please let me know if I did anything wrong. Thank you.